# Sort Area 51 proposals by nearness to completion

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, sorting, site-proposal

Right now there are four sort orders for proposals:

- hot
- followed
- newest
- popular

Please consider adding one more:

- completion

Although a better title might be in order, the essential idea is to sort sites by how close they are to being completed - ie, the sites with the longest bar appear at the top.

Unfortunately some of the proposals closest to completion aren't very "hot" or "popular", so one has to search for them.

Comment: I've just been through the entire list of proposals listed by "hottest" from start to finish, and I can't see any of those proposals closest to completion which aren't very "hot" or "popular" that you mention.

Comment: @Kinopiko - there are a lot of proposals on the second page of those two sort orders which are further toward completion than many of those that are on the first page.  Proposals are generally going to be "popular" and "hot" in spurts.  Further, when the beta is done and the site is swamped with many more proposals, I expect this issue to get worse.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be implemented now as the [**progress**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) tab.